# vue2 list return mixed string or component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In loop like this, I mostly just iterate over item values as strings, but sometimes need to return rendered component, for example build link element, or dropdown menu, for that table cell - need to find a way to return other component output instead of raw html string

```
  <tr class="listing-item listing-item-category">
    <td v-for="td in headeritems">{{val(td.k)}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Is that even possible? I've found no mention of this, how should the method code go to return other component output? I know I would have to use v-html, but how to get it?

Comment: is there any value exists to find component or string in "headeritems"? If so use this tag <component v-bind:is="Component Name" ></component> to render component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we have a list like this:

```
headerItems: [
  {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Some text'
  },
  {
    type: 'img',
    props: {
      src: 'http://some-where....'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'my-component',
    value: 'v-model value',
    props: {
      prop1: 10,
      prop2: 'Blah bla',
    },
    events: {
      myEvt: () => console.log('myEvt has fired')
    }
  },
],
```

So, We can render it:

```
<tr>
  <td
      v-for="(item, i) in headerItems" :key="i"
  >
    <div v-if="item.type === 'text'"> {{ item.value }}</div>
    <component
        v-else
        :is="item.type"
        v-model="item.value"
        v-bind="item.props"
        v-on="item.events"
    />
  </td>
</tr>
```